# Why std::log10(16.0) / std::log10(2.0) != std::log2(16.0)?

Tags: c++

I just realized that in C++ std::log2((float)16) returns 4 but replacing with std::log10((float)16) / std::log10(2.0) returns 4.0000001902931812. 
I am storing my answer in a double variable.

I am not sure why ?

The replacement works nicely in windows calculator and matlab.

Comment: Why do you expect it to be equal? Numerical inaccuracy are understandable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: `std::log10((float)16)` why do you cast to `float` if you want a `double` in the end?

Comment: `std::log10(2.0)` is not  equal to the log10 of 2, just near it.  Rest of the calculation propagates that approximation.  Same for `std::log10((float)16)`.

Comment: If you want a `double` literal, include a decimal (`10.`). If you want a `float` use the `f` suffix (`10.f`).